# How to get distinct fields from elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to ES and have created an index called vehicle with the data like below :

```
_source": {
           "catalogName": "EPE",
           "makeId": 1,
           "modelName": "GRAND PRIX SPECIAL",
           "catalogId": 1,
           "modelId": 22,
           "regionId": 6,
           "regionName": "All Regions",
           "vehicleId": 302,
           "engineName": "2-399  .4L",
           "makeName": "AMC-EAGLE",
           "engineId": 26,
           "yearId": 1991
        }
```

I'd like to pass the yearId and get all the distinct value of makeId and makeName. 
A sql query should be like
`"Select distinct makeId, makeName from vehicle where yearId =1991".` 
Please let me know, how to achieve the same in Elasticsearch (5.1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`terms` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) to achieve that:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "yearId": 1991
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "make_ids": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "makeId"
      }
    },
    "make_names": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "makeName"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, I'm pretty sure that your `makeName` field is of `text` type, so you won't get exactly what you expect. If you make that field a `keyword` instead, you'll get the desired output.

**UPDATE**

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "yearId": 1991
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "make_ids": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "makeId"
      }
      "aggs": {
        "make_names": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "makeName"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my query but, my problem here is, it returns two aggregations and one contains `makeId`,  while other contains `makeName`. In that case I'd not know which makeid has which makeName.

Comment: If you want you can nest them. See my updated answer

Comment: This is not equivalent to the SQL query as it may not return all combinations of (makeId, makeName) due to the default result size of 10 per aggregation.